# How to reconcile types between `hakyll` and `hakyll-images`

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I am trying to use [`hakyll`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll) and [`hakyll-images`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-images) to implement an example from the `hakyll-images` Readme which performs an image scaling as I will need to do. The types do not unify for the given example and I am seeking advice on how to proceed.

The failing example from the [`hakyll-images` Readme](https://github.com/LaurentRDC/hakyll-images#readme) is below.

```
import Hakyll
import Hakyll.Images        ( loadImage
                            , scaleImageCompiler
                            )
main = hakyll $ do
    -- Scale images to fit within a 600x400 box
    -- Aspect ratio will be preserved
    match "images/*" $ do
        route idRoute
        compile $ loadImage
            >>= scaleImageCompiler 600 400
```

Attempting to compile gives an error:

```
site.hs:12:9: error:
    • No instance for (Writable
                         hakyll-images-0.3.1:Hakyll.Images.Common.Image)
        arising from a use of ‘compile’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        compile $ loadImage >>= scaleImageCompiler 600 400
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘do route idRoute
            compile $ loadImage >>= scaleImageCompiler 600 400’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        match "images/*"
          $ do route idRoute
               compile $ loadImage >>= scaleImageCompiler 600 400
   |
12 |         compile $ loadImage >>= scaleImageCompiler 600 400
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The error is because type `Image`, defined by `loadImage`, is required by `compile` to be an instance of typeclass `Writable`. The types of the functions used from `hakyll` and `hakyll-images`, copied from the hackage documentation, are shown below.

```
    route :: Routes -> Rules ()
    idRoute :: Routes
    compile :: (Binary a, Typeable a, Writable a) => Compiler (Item a) -> Rules ()
    loadImage :: Compiler (Item Image)
    scaleImageCompiler :: Width -> Height -> Item Image -> Compiler (Item Image)
```

`Image` is defined in [`hakyll-images`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-images-0.3.1/docs/Hakyll-Images.html#t:Image) as `type Image = Image_ ByteString`.
I am not sure what `Image_` is; its definition is not linked in that documentation for the [`Hakyll.Images` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-images-0.3.1/docs/Hakyll-Images.html#t:Image).

In any case, it appears that the example from `hakyll-images`'s Readme does not compile due to `Image` not being an instance of `Writable`. I'm wondering if perhaps the `hakyll-images` package became out-of-sync with `hakyll` at some point leading to the example no longer compiling.

Does this assessment seem correct?
What do you suggest for how might I approach a solution?

I am considering:

- Updating `hakyll-images` by somehow adding a `Writable` instance for `Image`.
- Using some other set or combination of functions to perform the aspect-ratio-preserving image scalings.
- Ditching `hakyll-images` and finding some other way to scale the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is a bug that made its way into the hakyll-images 0.3.1 release. It was fixed subsequently in hakyll-images 0.4 and above. Simply update to the latest version to get rid of this problem.

This was a gross oversight and tests have been added such that this will not happen again.

If you wanted to implement the instances yourself, you can take a look at how it is done [here](https://github.com/LaurentRDC/hakyll-images/blob/master/library/Hakyll/Images/Common.hs).

Comment: Ah, I see I was using an older version and it is fixed in the latest. Thank you!